# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type on ARM but not x86

Tags: c, gcc, arm, beagleboneblack, icmp

I got this error while compiling on beaglebone (of coure I have included `netinet/ip_icmp.h`):

```
src/network.c: In function 'ping':
src/network.c:74:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'setuid' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
src/network.c:74:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getuid' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
src/network.c:88:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/network.c:89:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
src/network.c:118:14: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

but it only occurs on ARM platform (beaglebone). On my x86 everything works fine.
Here some useful information:

```
root@beaglebone:~/mips# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.6.3-14' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14)
```

84 to 89 lines form `network.c`:

```
struct icmp *pkt;
pkt = (struct icmp *) packet;
memset(pkt, 0, sizeof(packet));
pkt->icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
pkt->icmp_cksum = in_cksum((unsigned short *) pkt, sizeof(packet));
```

I found answers telling to use flag `-D__USE_BSD` but it did not work.

Does anyone either know:

1. How to make this program work?
2. How to write a simple ping program not using `<netinet/ip_icmp.h>`?

Comment: Run only the pre-processor (`-E` flag to `gcc`) to see if `struct icmp` is defined. If not, look at the header which suppose to define it (presumably `netinet/ip_icmp.h`) and see if any flags should be defined for the definition to be included.

Comment: Yes it's duplicate.  Thx

Comment: The solution is the same but question is different. There was just warring about getresuid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add definition of GNU extensions before inclusion of headers:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

or -`D_GNU_SOURCE` flag to the compiler.